# React-quill editor with socket.io creates infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, quill, react-quill

**Context:** I'm trying to create a live editor. So that multiple users can see the changes live.
As an editor, I'm using [react-quill](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill). And for emitting data, I'm using [socket](https://socket.io/).

**Idea:**

- While editing from the client emits the changes.
- Socket server will receive the changes and emit for all connections.
- the client will receive the emitted change and show it up on all editor.

**Problem:**
While typing(quickly) on the editor it automatically emitting the content.

Client side:

```
export const QuillEditor = () => {
  ...
  ...
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  socket.on('emittedText', ({ content }) => {
    setValue(content);
  });

  const emitEditorData = (content: any) => {
    socket.emit('editorText', { content: content, id: id });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ReactQuill
        style={{ height: 300 }}
        placeholder="Type and share..."
        theme="snow"
        value={value}
        onChange={(content, delta, editor) => {
          emitEditorData(content);
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Server side:

```
// handle socket connections and emits
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('editorText', ({ content, id }) => {
    //id for group data store
    editorText[id] = content;
    io.emit('emittedText', { content });
  });
});
```

Is it a react-quill issue or I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `onChange` in React is `oninput` in standard JS, and you put `emitEditorData` there, so yes it will fire after every key pressed. When do you need it to emit the changes?

Comment: @Tyblitz thanks for your response. I just wanna emit the content on every keystroke.

Comment: Your problem: "it emits on every keystroke". Your solution: "it should emit on every keystroke". So there is no problem? Or you need a timeout delay?

Comment: No, I'm unsure you get it correctly or not.
**My problem:** It emits automatically even if I don't type (and it occurs if I type quickly).
@Tyblitz

Comment: Try `if (content !== value) setValue(content)` in the on emittedText function